# How to concurrently get data in multiple tabs in puppeteer crawler?

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer

I want to get data of several pages at the same time using the puppteer module.

How do I run the crawl command for each tab at the same time?

I think using `Promise.all (pages Array)` solves my question.

Can it be?